# How can I enable developer mode in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, template

How to enable developer mode function  in magento2  please check the solution for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and safest way to switch Magento 2 to developer mode is by using special CLI command. Here is what you need to do:

1. Log in to your store via SSH/CLI and navigate to the root of your store.
2. Clean generated classes and other entities to prevent unchecked
   errors with the command `rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/*`
3. Switch to developer mode using the command `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

After running the latter command you will see log message below, which marks successful switching.

Switched to developer mode

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal or ssh, you need to hit following command

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

After running that command, you can check mode by hitting command

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```